# locals() vs globals() in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, local-variables

In the following wrapped function:

```
def info(self):
    a = 4
    def _inner():
        b = 5
        print ('LOCALS',locals())
        print ('GLOBALS', globals())
    _inner()
```

It prints the following in `python3.6`:

```
LOCALS {'b': 5}
GLOBALS {'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'info': <function info at 0x1029d3598>}
```

Why isn't `a`, the free variable, included in the `_inner` [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#locals)? From the docs it says:

> **locals()**
>
> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. **Free variables are returned by `locals()` when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks**.

Additionally, are class variables always hidden from `locals()`? For example:

```
class X:
    b = 2
    def info(self):
        a = 3
        print (locals())

>>> X().info()
{'a': 3, 'self': <__main__.X object at 0x102aa6518>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free variables are returned, the docs aren't wrong… but a free variable only exists for the inner function if it's used in it. Otherwise it's not loaded into the local scope. Try adding a simple `b += a` right after `b = 5` and you're gonna see `LOCALS {'b': 9, 'a': 4}` printed, just the way you expected.

As for class (and instance) variables, the above applies all the same, but with one caveat: these variables must be accessed through the `self` (or `cls`) object and that is what will show up in `locals()` instead.

Comment: Can you clarify the second paragraph? `locals()` has no arguments, so do you call `self.locals()` and `cls.locals()`?